# UPDATE with WHERE in sub select

Tags: mysql

I have a flat table containing posts and comments. Currently posts and comments are not really connected to each other, I only know, that comments reside immediately before (in terms of the id column) their corresponding post.

The first step to improvement is to create a "commentforid" column and fill it appropriately:

```
UPDATE mytable t
SET t.commentforid = (SELECT x.id
                      FROM mytable x
                      WHERE x.origin = 'POST'
                      AND x.id > t.id
                      LIMIT 1)
WHERE t.origin = 'COMMENT'
```

However, the query fails with

> You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

Does anyone know what the problem is? I can't make anything out of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to the fact you are updating the same table you are selecting  you could override this situation using a temp table

Try using  a dinamic from table

```
  UPDATE mytable t
  SET t.commentforid = (SELECT x.id

                        FROM ( select z.id from mytable z
                        WHERE x.origin = 'POST' ) x on  x.id > t.id
                        LIMIT 1)
  WHERE t.origin = 'COMMENT'
```

Comment: There is a minimum time of minutes you have to wait before being able to do so.

Comment: @DR   .  thanks  .. i have not looked  at the time in comment .. anyway  many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear. It is telling you that you cannot get the new value from the same table you are updating.

Why?

Imagine that (even as a mistake) you are trying to update a field in a record using the same record and field value. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the underlying problem, @scaisEdge has provided a workaround.

Comment: An alternative approach would be (and this is the way I prefer as it makes code easier to read and understand): Get the new value for the field in a single select statement (which would be the inner select), and then user the retrieved value in an update statement (your outer select). Yes, I know, some people would disagree, but one of the golden rules in Software Engineering (unfortunately forgotten or unknown by many) is **you don't write code for you, but for others who may need to read it and understand it**.